# Julia: 2d array assignment

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, julia

I'm trying to do the assignment in the 2d array with the nested loop. I'm trying to access the elements of the array as follows. But I get a mistake. I've searched, but I didn't get results. How can I assign Julia in the 2d array?

```
for x in 1:total
          for y in 1:W
            @show (x, y)
            if agirliklar[x] <= y

                V[x][y] = getMax(V[x-1][y], degerler[x] + V[x-1][y - agirliklar[x]])


            else
                print("sa")
                V[x][y] = V[x-1][y]
            end
          end
end
```

BoundsError: attempt to access 7×6 Array{Int64,2} at index [0]

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xOR7.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRukL.png)

Comment: It would be useful to see (example) definitions of `total`, `W`, `agirliklar`, `degerler`, and `V`. But maybe it's just that `x-1` is one-off?

Answer (score 4):

In Julia arrays are 1-based not 0-based.

You try to access `V[x-1]` where `x` can take value of `1`.

Site note: always provide a minimum working example (MWE) rather than just dumping a part of your production code.

Answer (score 3):

(At least) two things are wrong here:

1. As @PrzemyslawSzufel says, ordinary Julia arrays are 1-indexed, so you cannot access them at index zero. Though it is possible to get special arrays that are 0-indexed.
2. If `V` is a 2D array, as you are saying, you cannot access it like this: `V[x][y]`. Instead you access them like this: `V[x, y]`. You can read more about this here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#man-array-indexing-1

Comment: If one of the answers solves your problem, please consider marking one of them as the accepted answer.